# extract password protected sfx archive using c#

Tags: c#, sfx

I have WinRAR SFX file. I know that I can extract archive using following code:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "unrar.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "x file.rar d:\myFolder";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

But how can I extract SFX file when it have known password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use -p as parameter
Assuming your password is *123456*

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "unrar.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "x -p123456 file.rar d:\myFolder";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your password is *mypassword*, you need to change your arguments line to this:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"x -pmypassword file.rar d:\myFolder";
```

Note that you shouldn't put a space after the `-p` before your password - or it'll prompt you.

I also added a `@` to mark the string as a literal, otherwise it'll try to treat the `\m` in the file name as an escape character.